# .htaccess deliver resource if either php or html file for it exists

Tags: .htaccess

I was tasked with migrating a legacy site to a new hoster and at the same time place a new website there. The old legacy site should still be able to be accessible using archive.domain.tld

Links on the legacy site look either like this: `/foo/bar/baz.php` or `/foo/bar/baz.html` but there are also a lot of links looking like `/foo/bar/baz`. It seams that the old provider had some kind of rule in their apache config, to first look if a resource exists, and if not, to see if the resource would exist when adding `.php` and if not, if the resource would exist, if adding `.html`.

What I'd like to archive is the same behaviour.
Request to `https://archive.domain.tld/foo/bar/baz`

1. Check if /foo/bar/baz is a file, if so deliver it
2. Check if /foo/bar/baz.php is a file, if so deliver it
3. Check if /foo/bar/baz.html is a file, if so deliver it

I know, I could rewrite all traffic, to a single `.php` file like for example Symfony does, but how can I achieve this "routing" using a `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your Apache config or root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Perfect, exact what I was looking for! (I had a way more ugly solution "working" before, but this is just what I was looking for!), Edit: Have to wait for 6 more minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: One more thing I would suggest to keep these rules with comments so that website admins are aware of what each rule is doing.